# generate sound in assembly for IC 2051

Tags: assembly, embedded, 8051

1) i am iPhone developer but need a little work on assembly, i have to code in assembly language which generate sound (suppose a beep sound)

2) then i have to convert this .asm file to .hex file and write it to programming IC 2051 after that i have to connect it with hardware (i have) which generate sound

i am stuck with the First part, any help will be highly appreciated as i am stuck in it since weeks

following is my sample code

```
section .text
    global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                 ;tell linker entry point

    mov edx, len        ;message length
    mov ecx, msg        ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1          ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4          ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

    mov eax, 1          ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

section .data

MOV     DX,2000          ; Number of times to repeat whole routine.

MOV     BX,1             ; Frequency value.

MOV     AL, 10110110B    ; The Magic Number (use this binary number only)
OUT     43H, AL          ; Send it to the initializing port 43H Timer 2.

NEXT_FREQUENCY:          ; This is were we will jump back to 2000 times.

MOV     AX, BX           ; Move our Frequency value into AX.

OUT     42H, AL          ; Send LSB to port 42H.
MOV     AL, AH           ; Move MSB into AL  
OUT     42H, AL          ; Send MSB to port 42H.

IN      AL, 61H          ; Get current value of port 61H.
OR      AL, 00000011B    ; OR AL to this value, forcing first two bits high.
OUT     61H, AL          ; Copy it to port 61H of the PPI Chip
                         ; to turn ON the speaker.

MOV     CX, 100          ; Repeat loop 100 times
DELAY_LOOP:              ; Here is where we loop back too.
LOOP    DELAY_LOOP       ; Jump repeatedly to DELAY_LOOP until CX = 0


INC     BX               ; Incrementing the value of BX lowers 
                         ; the frequency each time we repeat the
                         ; whole routine

DEC     DX               ; Decrement repeat routine count

CMP     DX, 0            ; Is DX (repeat count) = to 0
JNZ     NEXT_FREQUENCY   ; If not jump to NEXT_FREQUENCY
                         ; and do whole routine again.

                         ; Else DX = 0 time to turn speaker OFF

IN      AL,61H           ; Get current value of port 61H.
AND     AL,11111100B     ; AND AL to this value, forcing first two bits low.
OUT     61H,AL           ; Copy it to port 61H of the PPI Chip
                         ; to turn OFF the speaker.
```

Read more: http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/make-sound-from-the-speaker-in-assembly/8255-8255-8284-asm-program-example.asp#ixzz3FNK0E1U2

Comment: I think maybe you're confused - the 2051 is an 8051-compatible micro-controller - you can't run x86 code on it.

Comment: what i have to do is just produce single beep with 2051, do you suggest any code?

Comment: First you will need to familiarise yourself with the 2051 itself, and the details of the evaluation board or whatever hardware you are using for this. One of the I/O pins will need to be connected to a loudspeaker or audio output jack. This pin will then need to be configured as a DAC or PWM output. You have a fairly steep learning curve ahead of you - good luck!

Comment: Is the point about being an iPhone developer at all relevant here!?

Answer (score 2):

The link posted is about x86 hardware and 8255 PPI - neither of which is of interest given your hardware. Your "sample code" is of little use to you as an example of how to do this on your hardware, it is a different instruction set, and different hardware.  Moreover it is a very crude and in CPU terns expensive method of generating sound in any case.

Your chip has two 16 bit timer/counters that can each drive a pin directly - you don't need assembler; you could just as well use a high-level language (C being the most likely for that platform).  Either way, you can simply program one timer to output a signal at the desired frequency with zero software overhead while running, then stop the timer after the desired period (for which you might use the second timer/counter).

If you have to use assembler, then first you need to learn the 8051 instruction set, then there will be minor syntax and directive differences depending on which assembler/linker tool-chain you will be using.  Secondly you will need familiarity with the hardware specification for your part and board and know how the speaker is connected to it and driven.

Essentially you have chosen to start from the wrong place using irrelevant information as a starting point.

---

### **[Edit]**

I am not familiar with the AT89C2051 specifically and it is a long time since I used an MCS-51 of any kind, but it using a hardware PWM may not be possible, in which case you can toggle the GPIO pin in the timer interrupt as described in the assembler and C examples [here](http://www.8051projects.net/pulse-width-modulation/8051-pwm-example.php).  Either way, these examples are far closer to what you need that what you are currently trying to use!